# Why does a MVC view not have access to constants internal to the project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, constants, access-modifiers

Something I encountered today at work, I tried to make a view that used a constant in a class in order to construct a query string. The code works perfectly fine when the constant is public but not when the constant is internal.

Here is the model:

```
public class LookupListModel
{
    internal const string ContactGroupTypeList = "ContactGroupType";

    // The below works fine
    //public const string ContactGroupTypeList = "ContactGroupType";
}
```

And the view (correct @using is at the top):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact group types", "Lookup", new { list = LookupListModel.ContactGroupTypeList })</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The view is compiled into another assembly, that's why the `internal const` does not work.

Comment: Thanks, thought it would have been something like that.

Comment: Fair enough. But what about a public const? That doesn't work either.

Comment: @East of Nowhere, according to the OP `public const` does work. Is your case a `public const` within an internal class?

Comment: Ah no it turns out I just made a simple mistake: I first tried to access it in the view like @Model.MyConst --- forgetting that Model is the *instance*, and of course all consts have to be accessed by the class name. My public const is working fine with my View.  :-)

Comment: Is there a way around this? For example, can I force the view to be compiled into the same assembly?

Comment: @Soenhay, not that I know of. In theory, you could make the internals visible to another assembly, but you would need that assembly name and I also don't know if there's a way to know that assembly name in advance.